# Can long integer routines benefit from SSE?

Tags: performance, integer, sse, bignum, arbitrary-precision

I'm still working on routines for arbitrary long integers in C++. So far, I have implemented addition/subtraction and multiplication for 64-bit Intel CPUs.

Everything works fine, but I wondered if I can speed it a bit by using SSE. I browsed through the SSE docs and processor instruction lists, but I could not find anything I think I can use and here is why:

- SSE has some integer instructions, but most instructions handle floating point. It doesn't look like it was designed for use with integers (e.g. is there an integer compare for less?)
- The SSE idea is SIMD (same instruction, multiple data), so it provides instructions for 2 or 4 independent operations. I, on the other hand, would like to have something like a 128 bit integer add (128 bit input and output). This doesn't seem to exist. (Yet? In AVX2 maybe?)
- The integer additions and subtractions handle neither input nor output carries. So it's very cumbersome (and thus, slow) to do it by hand.

My question is: is my assessment correct or is there anything I have overlooked? Can long integer routines benefit from SSE?  In particular, can they help me to write a quicker add, sub or mul routine?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the past, the answer to this question was a solid, "no". But as of 2017, the situation is changing.

But before I continue, time for some background terminology:

1. Full Word Arithmetic
2. Partial Word Arithmetic

**Full-Word Arithmetic:**

This is the standard representation where the number is stored in base 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup> using an array of 32-bit or 64-bit integers. 
Many bignum libraries and applications (including GMP) use this representation.

In full-word representation, every integer has a unique representation. Operations like comparisons are easy. But stuff like addition are more difficult because of the need for carry-propagation.

It is this carry-propagation that makes bignum arithmetic almost impossible to vectorize.

**Partial-Word Arithmetic**

This is a lesser-used representation where the number uses a base less than the hardware word-size. For example, putting only 60 bits in each 64-bit word. Or using base `1,000,000,000` with a 32-bit word-size for decimal arithmetic.

The authors of GMP call this, "nails" where the "nail" is the unused portion of the word.

In the past, use of partial-word arithmetic was mostly restricted to applications working in non-binary bases. But nowadays, it's becoming more important in that it allows carry-propagation to be delayed.

---

**Problems with Full-Word Arithmetic:**

Vectorizing full-word arithmetic has historically been a lost cause:

1. SSE/AVX2 has no support for carry-propagation.
2. SSE/AVX2 has no 128-bit add/sub.
3. SSE/AVX2 has no 64 x 64-bit integer multiply.*

*AVX512-DQ adds a lower-half 64x64-bit multiply. But there is still no upper-half instruction.

Furthermore, x86/x64 has plenty of specialized *scalar* instructions for bignums:

- Add-with-Carry: `adc`, `adcx`, `adox`.
- Double-word Multiply: Single-operand `mul` and `mulx`.

In light of this, both bignum-add and bignum-multiply are difficult for SIMD to beat scalar on x64. Definitely not with SSE or AVX.

With AVX2, SIMD is almost competitive with scalar bignum-multiply if you rearrange the data to enable "vertical vectorization" of 4 *different* (and independent) multiplies of the same lengths in each of the 4 SIMD lanes.

AVX512 will tip things more in favor of SIMD again assuming vertical vectorization.

But for the most part, "horizontal vectorization" of bignums is largely still a lost cause unless you have many of them (of the same size) and can afford the cost of transposing them to make them "vertical".

**Vectorization of Partial-Word Arithmetic**

With partial-word arithmetic, the extra "nail" bits enable you to delay carry-propagation.

So as long as you as you don't overflow the word, SIMD add/sub can be done directly. In many implementations, partial-word representation uses signed integers to allow words to go negative.

Because there is (usually) no need to perform carryout, SIMD add/sub on partial words can be done equally efficiently on both vertically and horizontally-vectorized bignums.

Carryout on horizontally-vectorized bignums is still cheap as you merely shift the nails over the next lane. A full carryout to completely clear the nail bits and get to a unique representation usually isn't necessary unless you need to do a comparison of two numbers that are almost the same.

Multiplication is more complicated with partial-word arithmetic since you need to deal with the nail bits. But as with add/sub, it is nevertheless possible to do it efficiently on horizontally-vectorized bignums.

AVX512-IFMA (coming with Cannonlake processors) will have instructions that give the full 104 bits of a 52 x 52-bit multiply (presumably using the FPU hardware). This will play very well with partial-word representations that use 52 bits per word.

**Large Multiplication using FFTs**

For really large bignums, multiplication is most efficiently done using [Fast-Fourier Transforms (FFTs)](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/fft.html).

FFTs are completely vectorizable since they work on independent `double`s. This is possible because fundamentally, the representation that FFTs use *is*
a partial word representation.

---

To summarize, vectorization of bignum arithmetic is possible. But sacrifices must be made.

If you expect SSE/AVX to be able to speed up some existing bignum code without fundamental changes to the representation and/or data layout, that's not likely to happen.

But nevertheless, bignum arithmetic is possible to vectorize.

---

Disclosure:

I'm the author of [y-cruncher](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/) which does plenty of large number arithmetic.

Comment: Great answer. I guess I'm another one of the many who have tried and failed.

Comment: But I don't understand the point about "No 128-bit integer add/sub." Why is this a problem? The general purpose/scalar registers don't have hardware for this either. The way to do this is two store hi and low in separate SIMD registers.

Comment: [I also think the lack of carry propagation is only a deal breaker with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923192/practical-bignum-avx-sse-possible/27978043#27978043)

Comment: @Zboson Scalar instructions have add-with-carry. Which is good enough to implement 128-bit add/subs efficiently. It's worth mentioning that Knights Corner Xeon Phi has SIMD add-with-carry using the mask registers. But they took it out of AVX512. I surmise that it complicated the design since it requires that the mask registers be wired up with the execution units.

Comment: Your statement "No 64 x 64-bit integer multiply. (low or high...)" is imprecise. AVX512 will have 64x64 to 64 (low) but even if it was as fast as 32x32 to 64 it would hot help much. The real problem is no 64x64 to 128. I guess  I mean the statement should be "No 64 x 64-bit integer multiply. (low and high...)"

Comment: @Mysticial, I was not aware that Knights Corner had add-with carry with mask registers. That's interesting.