# Visual C++ x64 add with carry

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 64-bit, inline-assembly, intrinsics

Since there doesn't seem to be an intrinsic for ADC and I can't use inline assembler for x64 architecture with Visual C++, what should I do if I want to write a function using add with carry but include it in a C++ namespace?

(Emulating with comparison operators is not an option.  This 256 megabit add is performance critical.)

Comment: Tell us more about this "256 megabit add".  It's quite likely that doing multiple adds at once using SIMD will be considerable faster, even considering that carries have to be handled as an extra step.

Comment: I did that bit of research already.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866973/can-long-integer-routines-benefit-from-sse.

Comment: @jnm2 - The x64 way seems to be writing separate assembly code and call that from your C++ function. The assembler is already part of the package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[There is now an instrinsic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977022.aspx) for `ADC` in MSVC: `_addcarry_u64`. The following code

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    uint64_t x1;
    uint64_t x2;
    uint64_t x3;
    uint64_t x4;
} uint256;

void add256(uint256 *x, uint256 *y) {
    unsigned char c = 0;
    c = _addcarry_u64(c, x->x1, y->x1, &x->x1);
    c = _addcarry_u64(c, x->x2, y->x2, &x->x2);
    c = _addcarry_u64(c, x->x3, y->x3, &x->x3);
    _addcarry_u64(c, x->x4, y->x4, &x->x4);
}

int main() {
    //uint64_t x1, x2, x3, x4;
    //uint64_t y1, y2, y3, y4;
    uint256 x, y;
    x.x1 = x.x2 = x.x3 = -1; x.x4 = 0;
    y.x1 = 2; y.x2 = y.x3 = y.x4 = 0;

    printf(" %016" PRIx64 "%016" PRIx64 "%016" PRIx64 "%016" PRIx64 "\n", x.x4, x.x3, x.x2, x.x1);
    printf("+");
    printf("%016" PRIx64 "%016" PRIx64 "%016" PRIx64 "%016" PRIx64 "\n", y.x4, y.x3, y.x2, y.x1);
    add256(&x, &y);
    printf("=");
    printf("%016" PRIx64 "%016" PRIx64 "%016" PRIx64 "%016" PRIx64 "\n", x.x4, x.x3, x.x2, x.x1);
}
```

produces the following assembly output from Visual Studio Express 2013

```
mov rdx, QWORD PTR x$[rsp]
mov r8, QWORD PTR x$[rsp+8] 
mov r9, QWORD PTR x$[rsp+16]
mov rax, QWORD PTR x$[rsp+24]
add rdx, QWORD PTR y$[rsp]
adc r8, QWORD PTR y$[rsp+8]
adc r9, QWORD PTR y$[rsp+16]
adc rax, QWORD PTR y$[rsp+24]
```

which has one `add` and three `adc` as expected.

Edit:

There seems to be some confusion as to what `_addcarry_u64` does. If you look at Microsoft's documentation for this which I linked to at the start of this answer it shows that it does not require any special hardware. This produces `adc` and it will work on all x86-64 processors (and `_addcarry_u32` would work on even older processors). It works fine on the Ivy Bridge system I tested it on.

However, `_addcarryx_u64` does require `adx` (as shown in MSFT's documentation) and indeed it fails to run on my Ivy Bridge System.

Comment: This answer requires a disclaimer, this instruction can only be used on 4th generation Core processors (Haswell and up).  Another 5 to 10 years and a support phone number before you can blindly depend on it to be available.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not able to confirm that. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @HansPassant, your wrong, this works fine on my Ivy Bridge system and it should work fine on all x86-64 processors. Did you read my answer? Did you notice that the compiler produced `adc` and not `adcx`? I updated the answer so that you can even test it on your own system (I assume you can find one before Broadwell) and look at the assembly generated. Now that I edited my question you can upvote me. It's the very least you can do.

Comment: Well, its fine for me to be wrong, this is not my post.  It is rather up to you to document what processors are in the "4th generation Core" set.  Yours is not so you get the old instruction.  Don't get a Haswell anytime soon, I guess.  Very nice processor btw.

Comment: @HansPassant, the ADX instructions were added to Broadwell, not Haswell. I do own a Haswell processor (but not Broadwell) but that's not what I tested this on. Why is up to me to document  what processors are "4th generation Core". This has nothing to do with my answer. [Maybe Intlel's documentation is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229371/addcarry-u64-and-addcarryx-u64-with-msvc-and-icc).

Comment: @HansPassant, Intel has updated their documentation both the white paper and [Intel intrinsic guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=138,140,138,140,138&text=_addcarry_u64). So I was right. Their documentation was wrong. `_addcarry_u64` only produces `adc`. Why did you trust the do documentation more than the assembly? It's time for you to remove your down vote and up vote me.

Answer (score 7):

VS2010 has built-in support for compiling and linking code written in assembly and translated by MASM (ml64.exe).  You just have to jump through a few hoops to enable it:

- Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer window, Build Customizations, tick "masm".
- Project + Add New Item, pick the C++ File template but name it *something.asm*
- Ensure you've got the x64 platform target for the project.  Build + Configuration Manager, select "x64" in the "Active solution platform" combo.  If missing, select `<New>` and pick x64 from the first combo.  If missing you'll have to re-run setup and add support for 64-bit compilers.

Write assembly code using MASM syntax, reference [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afzk3475%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Quick start tutorial [is here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly/).

The skeleton for the assembly code looks like this:

```
.CODE
PUBLIC Foo
Foo PROC
  ret                    ; TODO: make useful
Foo ENDP
END
```

And called from C++ code like this:

```
extern "C" void Foo();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Full debugging support is available, you'll typically want to at least use the Debug + Windows + Registers window.

Comment: The ideal solution in this case would be inline functions (inline assembly). Using an assembler and linking in the object files won't do this and 64-bit code in MSVC does not allow inline assembly. So this means the OP has to write many other functions (which the compiler probably does a good job with already) in assembly as well to avoid function calls.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a 256 bit integer using an array of `unsigned long long` and used x64 assembly to implement the add with carry. Here's the C++ caller:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C" void add256(unsigned long long *a, unsigned long long * b, unsigned long long *c);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned long long a[4] = {0x8000000000000001, 2, 3, 4};
    unsigned long long b[4] = {0x8000000000000005, 6, 7, 8};
    unsigned long long c[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    add256(a, b, c); // c[] == {6, 9, 10, 12};
    return 0;
}
```

The `add256` is implemented in assembly:

```
    ; void add256(unsigned long long *a, unsigned long long * b, unsigned long long *c)

.CODE
PUBLIC add256
add256 PROC

    mov                 qword ptr [rsp+18h],r8    
    mov                 qword ptr [rsp+10h],rdx    
    mov                 qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx    
    push                rdi    

    ; c[0] = a[0] + b[0];

    mov                 rax,qword ptr 16[rsp]
    mov                 rax,qword ptr [rax]    
    mov                 rcx,qword ptr 24[rsp]
    add                 rax,qword ptr [rcx]    
    mov                 rcx,qword ptr 32[rsp]
    mov                 qword ptr [rcx],rax    

    ; c[1] = a[1] + b[1] + CARRY;

    mov                 rax,qword ptr 16[rsp]
    mov                 rax,qword ptr [rax+8]    
    mov                 rcx,qword ptr 24[rsp]
    adc                 rax,qword ptr [rcx+8]    
    mov                 rcx,qword ptr 32[rsp]
    mov                 qword ptr [rcx+8],rax    

    ; c[2] = a[2] + b[2] + CARRY;

    mov                 rax,qword ptr 16[rsp]
    mov                 rax,qword ptr [rax+10h]    
    mov                 rcx,qword ptr 24[rsp]
    adc                 rax,qword ptr [rcx+10h]    
    mov                 rcx,qword ptr 32[rsp]
    mov                 qword ptr [rcx+10h],rax    

    ; c[3] = a[3] + b[3] + CARRY;

    mov                 rax,qword ptr 16[rsp]
    mov                 rax,qword ptr [rax+18h]    
    mov                 rcx,qword ptr 24[rsp]
    adc                 rax,qword ptr [rcx+18h]    
    mov                 rcx,qword ptr 32[rsp]
    mov                 qword ptr [rcx+18h],rax    

    ; }

    pop                 rdi    
    ret    

    add256              endp

    end
```

I know you indicating you didn't want an emulated add with carry solution, and wanted a high performing solution, but, still, you may consider the following C++ only solution which has a nice way of simulating 256 bit numbers:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned long long a[4] = {0x8000000000000001, 2, 3, 4};
    unsigned long long b[4] = {0x8000000000000005, 6, 7, 8};
    unsigned long long c[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    c[0] = a[0] + b[0]; // 6
    c[1] = a[1] + b[1] + (c[0] < a[0]); // 9
    c[2] = a[2] + b[2] + (c[1] < a[1]); // 10
    c[3] = a[3] + b[3] + (c[2] < a[2]); // 12
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being late, but the c++ solution is not correct. As simplification consider a = 01 and b=11 with carry = 1, then c=01 with carry=1 but c<a is false.