# Unresolved external error in very Simple x64 Assembly/C++ Application

Tags: c++, assembly

I started to learn assembly language because I'm interested in image processing and C++, and fortunately I found a series of videos about image processing using assembly language and C++  in youtube.

But when I try to implement my first app I get unresolved external in my GetValueFromAsm function 
so I need your help to find out my error.

This is my C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>


extern "C" int GetValueFromAsm();

int main()
{
     std::cout<<"Value From Asm "<< GetValueFromAsm()<<std::endl;
    _getch();
     return 0;
}
```

and this is my assembly code

```
.code
GetValueFromAsm proc
    mov rax,30
    ret
GetValueFromAsm endp
end
```

I'm using VS 2010/Windows 7 64bit and x64 application.

Comment: `<troll>`The symbol `Errro` is not found. Probably because it was misspelled (did you want to type `Error`?)`</troll>`

Comment: sehe makes a good point.  Exactly what is the error you're getting?  (MrGingerbear makes a good point too.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual C++ x64 add with carry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145644/visual-c-x64-add-with-carry)

Comment: ad i said my error was unresolved external in GetValueFromAsm function

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities come to mind "right away":

- Are you actually compiling and linking the assembler code with the rest of the program?
- The C symbols might be decorated, like the compiler using "_GetValueFromAsm"

Comment: this my steps when i wrote this code
1- right click ->Build Customization -> check masm
2- wrote code exactly as i did here but as you can see i got unresolved external in GetValueFromAsm