# Assembly ADC (add with carry)

Tags: assembly, x86, carryflag

```
mov eax, ptr_to_num1 ; little endian
mov ebx, ptr_to_num2 ; little endian
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx
clc
bytes_addition:
    mov dl, byte [eax+ecx] ; byte from shortest
    adc dl, byte [ebx+ecx]
    mov byte [eax+ecx], dl
    inc ecx
    cmp ecx, 4 ; counter, 
    jl bytes_addition
```

Consider at

EAX: 4F2252FF (big endian)

EBX: 00DFFC00 (big endian)

The result of this addition is wrong: 50024fff (big endian). It should be 50024eff. It looks like the carry flag is affected, but why?

Comment: If you're going to use that `cmp` in the loop you need to move your `clc` to the top of the loop.

Comment: I don't think so... This will always set carry to 0, but i use ADC.

Comment: My point is that `CMP` will modify the carry flag.  This means that it won't necessarily be in the state you expect it to be when the loop starts its next pass.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084204/problems-with-adc-sbb-and-inc-dec-in-tight-loops-on-some-cpus for discussion of how to loop without affecting the carry flag, and also without causing a partial-flag stall while doing it.  (e.g. LEA/JECXZ).  In your case, a full unroll of the loop (4x `adc/mov`) would be about as many instructions as your loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cmp` affects carry, which is how it's used for unsigned comparison.

You could start `ecx` at -4, then use `jnz bytes_addition`. You already have the `inc` there, which will set the zero flag when `ecx` becomes zero, and won't affect carry.

Of course this offset has to be compensated for, either by adding 4 to `eax` before the loop, or adding offsets of 4 in the addressing.

Comment: Thanks, i suspected there is the problem, but wasn't sure.