# Fastest way to set a Carry Flag

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly, carryflag

I'm doing a cycle to sum two arrays. My objective is do it by avoiding carry checks `c = a + b; carry = (c<a)`. I lost the `CF` when I do the loop test, with the `cmp` instruction.

Currently, i am using and the `JE`and `STC` to test and set the previously saved state of `CF`. But the jump takes more less 7 cycles, what it is a lot for what I want.

```
   //This one is working
   asm(
        "cmp $0,%0;"
        "je 0f;"
        "stc;"
    "0:"   
        "adcq %2, %1;"
        "setc %0"

    : "+r" (carry), "+r" (anum)
    : "r" (bnum)
   );
```

I already tried use the `SAHF` (2 + 2(mov) cycles), but that do not worked.

```
   //Do not works
   asm(
        "mov %0, %%ah;"
        "sahf;"
        "adcq %2, %1;"
        "setc %0"

        : "+r" (carry), "+r" (anum)
        : "r" (bnum)
   );
```

Anyone knows a way to set the `CF` more quickly? Like a direct move or something similar..

Comment: Are you doing 32 bits on a 64 bit machine?   or 64 bit adds on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: I am using a 64bit machine. For record, the `anum` and `bnum` are 8 bytes long.

Comment: Is the size of the array known at compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Looping without clobbering `CF` will be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084204/problems-with-adc-sbb-and-inc-dec-in-tight-loops-on-some-cpus).  See that link for some better asm loops.

Don't try to write just the `adc` with inline asm inside a C loop.  It's impossible for that to be optimal, because you can't ask gcc not to clobber flags.  Trying to learn asm with GNU C inline asm is harder than writing a stand-alone function, esp. in this case where you are trying to preserve the carry flag.

You could use `setnc %[carry]` to save and `subb $1, %[carry]` to restore.  (Or `cmpb $1, %[carry]` I guess.)  Or as Stephen points out, `negb %[carry]`.

`0 - 1` produces a carry, but `1 - 1` doesn't.

Use a `uint8_t` to variable to hold the carry, since you will never add it directly to `%[anum]`.  This avoids any chance of [partial-register slowdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/which-is-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).  e.g.

```
uint8_t carry = 0;
int64_t numa, numb;

for (...) {
    asm ( "negb   %[carry]\n\t"
          "adc    %[bnum], %[anum]\n\t"
          "setc   %[carry]\n\t"
          : [carry] "+&r" (carry), [anum] "+r" (anum)
          : [bnum] "rme" (bnum)
          : // no clobbers
        );
}
```

You could also provide an alternate constraint pattern for register source, reg/mem dest.  I used [an x86 `"e"` constraint](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) instead of `"i"`, because 64bit mode still only allows 32bit sign-extended immediates.  gcc will have to get larger compile-time constants into a register on its own.  Carry is early-clobbered, so even if it and `bnum` were both `1` to start with, gcc couldn't use the same register for both inputs.

This is still terrible, and increases the length of the loop-carried dependency chain from 2c to 4c (Intel pre-Broadwell), or from 1c to 3c (Intel BDW/Skylake, and AMD).

**So your loop runs at 1/3rd speed because you're using a kludge instead of writing the whole loop in asm.**

---

A previous version of this answer suggested adding the carry directly, instead of restoring it into `CF`.  This approach has a fatal flaw: it mixed up the incoming carry into this iteration with the outgoing carry going to the next iteration.

---

Also, `sahf` is Set AH from Flags.  `lahf` is Load AH into Flags (and it operates on the whole low 8 bits of flags.  Pair those instructions; don't use `lahf` on a 0 or 1 that you got from `setc`.

Read the insn set reference manual for any insns that don't seem to be doing what you expect.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: Unfortunately `add carry, a; add b, a` does not set the carry flag correctly in the case where there is carry-in and `a` is `0xffff....ffff`.

Comment: I already have done an implementation of the cycle without clobbering, and just using registers, but it just worked on my computer. When I put it on other one the result was segmentation fault, because the used registers were different. Note: The compilers were also different (gcc & icc).

Do you know if this always happens by switching the microarchitecture (ex: Sandy Bridge &  Haswell), or it is also because the compiler?

Comment: To the second example this works: `asm("mov %0, %%ah; "sahf; :"+r" (aux));
` `asm("adcq %2, %1;"
 "setc %0" : "+r" (aux), "+r" (anum) : "r" (bnum)); `

But unfortunately, these things happen: `movb   %dl, -0x3d(%rbp); movb   -0x3d(%rbp), %dl`

Comment: @HélderGonçalves: If you write your constraints wrong, you will have problems.  This is why inline asm is the hardest way to learn asm.  Also, if you're going to use `sahf`/`lahf`, you should use an `int` with an `"a"` constraint to force it to be in `eax`.  Always avoid writing `mov` instructions when you can get gcc to put stuff where you need it.  Often it can do so without extra instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That doesn't fix the problem; now you end up off by one, and still don't set carry correctly.  There's a few ways to fix this, one simple one is to add `-1` to carry, then do `adc b, a`.

Comment: You can also restore `carry` to `CF` by negating it, subject to the partial flags update hazard on some µarches.

Comment: @StephenCanon: I see now, I was turning an outgoing carry from `a+carry` into an incoming carry.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If the array size is known at compile time, you could do something like this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

#define str(s) #s
#define xstr(s) str(s)

#define ARRAYSIZE 4

asm(".macro AddArray2 p1, p2, from, to\n\t"
    "movq (\\from*8)(\\p2), %rax\n\t"
    "adcq %rax, (\\from*8)(\\p1)\n\t"
    ".if \\to-\\from\n\t"
    "   AddArray2 \\p1, \\p2, \"(\\from+1)\", \\to\n\t"
    ".endif\n\t"
    ".endm\n");

asm(".macro AddArray p1, p2, p3\n\t"
    "movq (\\p2), %rax\n\t"
    "addq %rax, (\\p1)\n\t"
    ".if \\p3-1\n\t"
    "   AddArray2 \\p1, \\p2, 1, (\\p3-1)\n\t"
    ".endif\n\t"
    ".endm");

int main()
{
   unsigned char carry;

   // assert(ARRAYSIZE > 0);

   // Create the arrays
   uint64_t *anum = (uint64_t *)malloc(ARRAYSIZE * sizeof(uint64_t));
   uint64_t *bnum = (uint64_t *)malloc(ARRAYSIZE * sizeof(uint64_t));

   // Put some data in
   memset(anum, 0xff, ARRAYSIZE * sizeof(uint64_t));
   memset(bnum, 0, ARRAYSIZE * sizeof(uint64_t));
   bnum[0] = 1;

   // Print the arrays before the add
   printf("anum: ");
   for (int x=0; x < ARRAYSIZE; x++)
   {
      printf("%I64x ", anum[x]);
   }
   printf("\nbnum: ");
   for (int x=0; x < ARRAYSIZE; x++)
   {
      printf("%I64x ", bnum[x]);
   }
   printf("\n");

   // Add the arrays
   asm ("AddArray %[anum], %[bnum], " xstr(ARRAYSIZE) "\n\t"
        "setc %[carry]" // Get the flags from the final add

       : [carry] "=q"(carry)
       : [anum] "r" (anum), [bnum] "r" (bnum)
       : "rax", "cc", "memory"
   );

   // Print the result
   printf("Result: ");
   for (int x=0; x < ARRAYSIZE; x++)
   {
      printf("%I64x ", anum[x]);
   }
   printf(": %d\n", carry);
}
```

This gives code like this:

```
mov    (%rsi),%rax
add    %rax,(%rbx)
mov    0x8(%rsi),%rax
adc    %rax,0x8(%rbx)
mov    0x10(%rsi),%rax
adc    %rax,0x10(%rbx)
mov    0x18(%rsi),%rax
adc    %rax,0x18(%rbx)
setb   %bpl
```

Since adding 1 to all f's will completely overflow everything, the output from the code above is:

```
anum: ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff
bnum: 1 0 0 0
Result: 0 0 0 0 : 1
```

As written, ARRAYSIZE can be up to about 100 elements (due to gnu's macro depth nesting limits).  Seems like it should be enough...